# Any suggestions for a vehicle [Nissan Frontier] outside temperature guage - dashboard mounted

Tags: temperature, air

Hubby's truck doesn't have an outside temp gauge.  He needs it for winter as he plows.  What suggestions do you have please [birthday present]  thank you!

Comment: Hi Sandie: for future reference, we try to avoid shopping questions in the main area as the information has as tendency to become out of date quickly. However, we almost always have chatty people hanging around in the chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop  Please feel free to stop by there any time you need more ideas for the Hub's truck. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I bought one of these years ago for a car that didn't have an outside temp gauge and it worked great. Bought it at Walmart but they have them at auto stores too. You just have to run the sensor to the front of the car and outside the engine compartment. The base unit mounts inside somewhere on the dash. The units are powered by one or two AA batteries.

Here's a picture of a similar one.

Hope this makes Hubby happy.

[image]